# Zero Coupon Swaps Convexity Adjustments

Tags: swaps, convexity

Can i check here if convexity adjustments are needed for zero coupon swaps?

Comment: Being that there aren't any coupon payments, generally, no convexity adjustments are needed.

Comment: In sterling when there was a LIBOR curve for forecasting and an OIS curve for discounting there were convexity adjustments for two reasons, 1) the cross-gamma on the discounting basis risk was large when hedged with IRS and 2) a small gamma effect from compounded libor affecting risk marginally differently to the risk created from OIS curve when rates moved.

When the ZCS and IRS hedges are in RFR and use the same curve for forecasting and discounting (e.g. SONIA) there is precisely zero convexity adjustment needed.